# Calculate tangent point on ellipse

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I'm trying to find a tangent point on an ellipse. Trying a lot, using answers found a.o. on this site, but obviously doing something wrong as I'm not getting any good results.

I've added a sketch, to help make it more clear.

The problem at hand:

I have an ellipse, and am basically looking for the $45^\circ$ tangent point, this is point P in the sketch.

The center of the ellipse is $(0,0)$.

$P$ is $200$ to the right from the origin, and $(b-22)$ up from the origin, so $P$ is at $(200, b-22)$.

For a given major radius $a$, I try to calculate the minor radius $b$.

The answer I need is in the form of $a = f(b)$.

How to do this?

(addition)
The formula I managed to derive in different ways before asking here (and which came back in the answers) is $ a = \sqrt{200 \frac{b^2}{b-22}} $. Now when I fill in b=30, I get a=150. That's impossible as in this case point P is not on the ellipse, it's somewhere out of the ellipse.

(solution)
First of all, thanks to all that helped out. In the end I realised I was much closer to the answer than I thought; but needed the final bits to put it all together. I've been drawing some nice ellipses now - those things are remarkably tricky to work with! Furthermore, to allow for the needed flexibility, I've replaced the value 200 for x in the image above, with the variable x.

The correct question is: what are the major and minor radiuses of an ellipse so that it passes through point P = (x,b-22) with slope -1?

Slope -1 at P:
$$a = \sqrt{\frac{xb^2}{b-22}} $$

Point P on the ellipse:
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{(b-22)^2}{b^2} = 1 $$

Substitute the first in the second, and solve:

$$b = \frac{22x-484}{x-44} $$

a in turn is caculated with the first formula.
For more details on how these formulas are derived, see also the replies below.

[image: sketch of the problem at hand]

Comment: isn't the slope 135?

Comment: why a=30,b=150 not valid?

Comment: Point P is on (200, b-22). If a<200, there is no point on the ellipse where x=200.

Comment: It is because at such situation a tangent of required slope is not possible.

Comment: OK, so that was my mistake, thinking there are more solutions. I see it now. So for that I'll have to make the x variable, which definitely works for my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the given constraints determine $b$; you are not free to take $b=30$.  As others have shown, the constraint on the tangent gives
$$ a = b\sqrt{\frac{200}{b-22}} $$
The constraint that $P$ be on the ellipse gives
$$ \frac{200^2}{a^2} + \frac{(b-22)^2}{b^2} = 1 $$
Use the first to eliminate $a$ from the second, and you'll get an equation for $b$, which is readily solved to give
$$ b = \frac{979}{14} \approx 69.9 $$

Comment: You must have miscalculated somewhere because this b doesn't give a reasonable a. I solved the same, and result is $b = \frac{3916}{156} \approx 25.1$, and that's finally an answer that makes sense.

Comment: Three good answers; had to choose one to accept; this includes the final step which is why you have the honour of an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Very close to what I figured out myself, but it still doesn't work: your solution does not give an answer where b > 22 as then it's a negative argument for the root. This is obviously wrong as b should be >22 at all times.

Comment: The slope should be $-1$, not $1$.

Comment: Indeed with the slope set at -1 it's the exact same solution I got myself already, just when doing the actual calculation the resulting numbers don't work.

Comment: @WoutervanMarle In what way does the actual calculation not work? Can you give an example? (The formula you derived, and an actual calculation showing that something goes wrong, really should be included in the main question so we're all working on the problem you really have.)

Comment: Made addition to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of the ellipse is $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$. Differentiate this to get $\frac{2x}{a^2}dx + \frac{2y}{b^2}dy = 0$, so $\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{b^2x}{a^2y}$.

At $(x,y)=(200,b-22)$, we want $\frac{dy}{dx} = -1$. So $-\frac{200b^2}{(b-22)a^2} = -1$, which gives $a=b\sqrt{\frac{200}{b-22}}$.

Comment: Different way, same solution again. I don't understand what is wrong here: when I use b=30, I get a=150. That's less than 200, and for that reason has to be wrong.

Comment: Given $b$, there is only one ellipse through $P$. In general, the tangent will not have slope $-1$ there. So your problem is only soluble for 'special' values of $b$.